# SQL 2008 Web Edition for Intranet web sites

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Can I use the SQL 2008 Web Edition for internal web sites (intranet), used only internally from my company, and not over the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. From: http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/ProductPage.aspx?pid=364

> The software may be used only to
>   support **public and Internet accessible**
>
> ```
> * Web pages
> * Web sites
> * Web applications
> * Web services
> ```

(The bold emphasis is mine)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Depending on the number of users you have you'll have to decide on licensing between server + CALs or CPU licenses.  As long as you are correctly licensed you can use any edition (except for Developer) for anything that you want.